# Set selected data for selectors and events selectors change in for loop vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need something that runs similar functionality of this jq in vuejs:
ex:

```
- html 
             @foreach($users as $user) 
                <td>
                    <selecter class="check-change" data-id="{{$user->id}}">
                        <opt @if($user->status == 'active') selected @endif value="active">Active</opt>
                        <opt @if($user->status == 'wait_confirm') selected @endif value="wait_confirm">Wait Confirm</opt>
                    <selecter>
                </td>`
- jq 
            `$('.check-change').on('change', function() {
                var new_value = this.value;
                -> send request update user (this.attr('data-id'))
            });
```

I'm stuck because I don't know how to check if and add attr selected for selector in vue js, and I also don't know how to get user id and selected option when that user's selecter changes.

Current code :

```
const items_status = [
{
    state: 'Active',
    abbr: 'active',
  },
  {
    state: 'Wait Confirm',
    abbr: 'wait_confirm',
  }
];
const selectedOption = ref({
    state: 'Wait Confirm',
    abbr: 'wait_confirm',
})
<tr
    v-for="user in users"
    :key="user.id"
    style="height: 3.75rem;"
    <td>
        <VSelect
            v-model="selectedOption"
            :hint="`${selectedOption.state}, ${selectedOption.abbr}`"
            :items="items_status"
            item-title="state"
            item-value="abbr"
            label="Select"
            persistent-hint
            return-object
            single-line
        />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger something when the selected option changes, then you can do that with a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watchers):

```
setup() {
    const options = [ ... ];

    const selectedOption = Vue.ref({ ... });

    Vue.watch(selectedOption, () => {
        // selectedOption changed
    });

    return {
        options,
        selectedOption
    };
}
```

If you want to customize the VSelect like you have in your first example, then you can replace the option component. But I believe Vuetify handles the active state already, so unless you need a specific design, you don't need to touch it.

```
<v-select v-model="selectedOption" :items="options" item-title="state" item-value="abbr" label="Select" return-object single-line>
    <template #item="{ item, props }">
        <v-list-item v-bind="{ ...props, title: undefined }">
            {{ item.value.abbr === selectedOption.abbr ? 'selected' : '' }} {{ item.title }}
        </v-list-item>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

Comment: Your answer makes me imagine that vuejs will take care of it when I set the v model as user.status, it's like temporarily changing that user.status on the client side. So I tried it according to your code and it worked although there were some points I didn't understand but at least for the time being it works as me intended. Thanks for preserving me my brain

Comment: [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model) seems to do some magic, but it's just syntax for binding a value and then setting the value when it's emitted from the component. If you want to be more explicit, then you could also do `:modelValue="selectedOption" @update:modelValue="selectedOption = $event"`. You could then provide a callback to `@update:modelValue` where you set the option and handle the option change logic without the watcher.